# ggvis graphic with group selection

Tags: r, graphics, ggvis

I want to use ggvis for data exploration (because I am familiar with ggplot2), and it would be of great help, due to many groups in my data sets, to be able to select and unselect groups to make different specific (data) comparisons.

```
set.seed(10)
dat <- data.frame(x=c(1:3,1:3),y=rnorm(6),groups=factor(rep(1:2,each=3)))
library(ggvis)

dat  %>% ggvis(~x, ~y) %>% layer_points(fill=~groups)
# i know this example does not work - but is that possible somehow?
dat  %>% ggvis(~x, ~y) %>% layer_points(fill=input_checkbox(~groups))
```

What I want at the end, is a graphic with which I can select a subset of groups by using radio buttons (for example).
Is there any way to do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/interactivity.html)

> **Limitations**
>
> Currently, interactive inputs can only be used in two places:
>
> 1. as arguments to transforms: `layer_smooths(span = input_slider(0, 1))`
> 2. as properties: `props(size = input_slider(10, 1000))`
>
> This means that **interactive inputs can only modify the data, not the
>   underlying plot specification**. In other words, **with only basic
>   interactivity there’s no way to add or remove layers**, or switch
>   between different datasets. This is a reasonable limitation because if
>   you’re doing exploration you can always create a new ggvis with R
>   code, or if you’re polishing a plot for presentation, you can embed it
>   in a Shiny app and gain full control over the plot.

---

For simple data exploration, one idea could be to use `filter()`:

```
set.seed(10)
dat <- data.frame(x = c(1:5,1:5,1:5), 
                  y = rnorm(15), groups = factor(rep(1:5,each=3)))
```

**Note**: I edited your initial dataset to illustrate the concept with more groups

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)

dat %>% ggvis(~x, ~y) %>% layer_points(fill = ~groups)
```

[image]

You could pass the arguments (either manually directly in your R code or with your radio buttons in a Shiny app) to `filter()` to isolate specific groups:

```
dat %>% 
  filter(groups == 1 | groups == 3) %>% 
  ggvis(~x, ~y) %>% layer_points(fill = ~groups)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know that this is possible with `filter()` - I already did it that way, but I wanted something interactive, which can be changed dynamically!

Comment: Unfortunately no - you cannot add `input_checkbox()` to filter - i think because this function is part of `ggvis` and `filter()` is a `dplyr` function.

Comment: with plain shiny, it would be no problem, from my point of view. but in a real life data exploration situation, I would never compute a shiny app. what I want, is something easy to use.

Comment: @Manuel Are you expecting to use dynamic checkboxes to filter your data without using Shiny ? If that is the case, then no, sadly, it's not possible. See the edit.

Comment: I found out in the meantime it´s possible with rCharts (http://ramnathv.github.io/posts/rcharts-nvd3/index.html) - but unfortunately the package is not well documented how the plot(s) can be customized in different ways.

Comment: @Manuel I tried the `rCharts` examples in the documentation but it seems that the `addFilters` parameter doesn't render properly on my system: `RStudio v0.99.332 - R v3.2.1 - rCharts v0.4.5 `